# How to open the right socket / handle new page with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to build a multi-page game application, but I'm having some trouble with socket.io. Everything was fine with emitting/receiving messages when I was on one page, but when I directed it to another page, the socket disconnects then reconnects, and I am unable to get any message that I wanted to send before the disconnect. I've read something about needing to reconnect the closed socket, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the relevant part of the server code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  socket.on("newGame", (name) => {
      let code = makeid(6);
      socket.emit("joinRoom", {code: code, name:name});
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected"); // the terminal prints disconnect then connect, but the socketid has changed
  });
});
```

And this is the relevant bit for the front end:

```
socket.emit("newGame", this.state.name);
window.location.href = `/setup`; // the line below works if this is commented out
socket.on("joinRoom", data => {console.log("hereeee")}); // not running!
```

Can I get some pointers / examples? I'm new to socket.io and node in general so I'm not sure what to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can establish your connection in react in the root component as any other component may be destructed and destruct the socket connection with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you just need to redirect ***after*** you receive the message from the server, like this:

**Client**

```js
socket.emit("newGame", this.state.name);
socket.on("joinRoom", data => {
  console.log("hereeee");
  // Do things with the data, such as saving it in localStorage,
  // to access it later
  window.location.href = `/setup`;
});
```

And if you want to keep the emitted data, you can save it in localStorage, and then get it again.

By the way, I'm making your client script receive the message **before** you redirect because I don't see any reason for you to redirect and **then** receive the message. If you do have to, I could show you a way to do that as well.

Hope this solves your problem! :)